# Find SU binary source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Where can I find the source code for the SU binary in linux? The entire OS is open source, so why can't I find it? I can find the SUDO source, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Unless you specify what OS you are using nobody will be able to help you. Linux is a kernel, not an OS.

Comment: Debian or Ubuntu. Either one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debian Stable:

```
$ which su
/bin/su

$ apt-file search /bin/su | grep "/bin/su$"
login: /bin/su

$ apt-cache show login | grep "Homepage"
Homepage: http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/

<open page, click Download, observe github link>
https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow
```

https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/su.c

Comment: Thank you very much. And I'm wondering where is the su.c for CentOS. I have found source for centos/coreutils [here](https://git.centos.org/rpms/coreutils/tree), but no content there. I also find gnu's coreutils [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/tree/master/src), but no su.c there.